# Assign CSS class to content

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i have downloaded a wordpress theme that assigns two different css classes (one for even and one for odd numbers) to its page sections via this php function:

```
if (in_array('type-page', $classes)) {
$classes[] = (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
```

Is there any way to change\rewrite the function to assign a custom css class to each page section progressively? E.g.

- Section One -> Css Class 001
- Section Two -> Css Class 002
- Section Three -> Css Class 003 
  and so on..

I reckon this is probably a noob question, but i'm totally unexperienced in php..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not enough code posted. What is `$j`? If it is the section, then just add a `Css-Class-$j`

Comment: please provide some sample html. how many sections are there?

Comment: Really sorry! This should be the whole function http://pastebin.com/SiLUykHv


Also, i'm not sure i'm allowed to link it, but the theme is http://wpdemo.themi.co/rythm/


About the number of sections, you can add as many as you like, the theme just proceeds to add two different css custom classes: one for the odd pages (white background) and one for the even ones (cream colored background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing to understand is that the first time this method is called $j is initialized to 0, on subsequent calls $j is incremented by 1 if 'type-page' is in the classes array.

Therefore a quick and easy way to implement a list of styles based on the value of $j is to add an array holding your classes.  And then assign the class indexed by $j on each method call that triggers this if block. Like so:

```
  public static function filterPostClass($classes)
        {

        // first we'll create an array of our classes these get indexed 0 to n-1 where n is the length of the array
        $classNames = array('Css Class 001', 'Css Class 002', 'Css Class 003'); // and so on ...

        static $j = 0;

        // then instead of 'even'/'odd', we assign the value in the $j'th index to the $classes var
        if (in_array('type-page', $classes)) {
            $classes[] = $classNames[$j];
            $j++;

        }
```

Comment: Aaaaand it worked perfectly! I'm truly sorry for replying so late, and very grateful for your help..

Thanks again!

(I also have a somewhat clearer idea about arrays :p)